# How to update Qt from 5.5.1 to 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: qt, qt5, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to update Qt from 5.5.1 to 5.7 or higher.

I tried `sudo apt-get install qt-default qtdeclarative5-dev` 
gives me following output on console:

> qtdeclarative5-dev is already the newest version (5.5.1-2ubuntu6).
>
> qt5-default is already the newest version (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.6).

How can I update Qt to 5.7 or higher version?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu packages in standard repository are always outdated. I suggest you install Qt from `.run` [file they provide](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer) .

But you can possibly [run into problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298040/building-qt5-quick-project-without-qt-creator-via-cmake), as i did, using Qt + CMake without Qt Creator

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062046/how-to-update-qt-from-5-5-1-to-5-9-5-on-ubuntu-16-04) and was able to update Qt to 5.11 using PPA following commands:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt-5.11.1-xenial
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt511-meta-full
```

For system wide usage, create `default.conf` file at `/etc/xdg/qtchooser` with following content:

```sh
/opt/qt511/bin
/opt/qt511/lib
```

That's it, it should be updated by now. `qmake -v` outputs the current Qt and qmake version

Comment: I got a reply: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.